# Magento 2 - Move swatch-options at the bottom

Tags: magento2, product, php, module

I try to move swatch-options in the product page at the bottom of the page, before "Write a review" zone, I use this code:

```
 <move element="product.info" destination="content" before="product.info.review"/>
```

but after this "**Add to Wishlist**" disappear.

What I can do to have the wishlist button?

Comment: Share your current screenshot of your product page , reviews coming in tab or out of tab ?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
 <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.review"/>
```

Comment: Hi is not work because is still in the right side, I need to be bottom because I need to have full width.

Comment: Every time when I try to change the position of product.info the wishlist button is not visible, I have the feeling that there is some conditions on the wishlist button. Is there any way to add that button manually?

Comment: I need to move color swatches below product name ,  can you please guide me how to do and please clear the file name and where can i place that file